# understanding the "ssh" man page

Tags: ssh

My purpose is to use `mkdir` on the remote host.

In the `ssh` man page which, on Ubuntu, comes from BSD, it says

```
If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a
 login shell.
```

The command would be the one at the end of this:

`ssh user@remoteHost command`

For my purpose the command would be `mkdir --parents path/folder`. What is the significance of the phrase "it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell"?

What does this mean? Does it mean that a non-login shell is used? My understanding is that both login and non-login shells involve `.bashrc` and so the difference is that the profile is not sourced for a non-login shell. Why would we want to ignore the profile of `user`?

Comment: The main idea (apart from which files are sourced) is to point out that after the command has been executed, the connection is immediately closed again - in contrast to `ssh` without a command specified where you would simply log in.

Comment: @Fiximan what you said makes far more sense than what the documentation writers said.

Answer (score 3):

> Does it mean that a non-login shell is used?

Yes. (Depends on what you mean by "login shell", though.)

> My understanding is that both login and non-login shells involve .bashrc and so the difference is that the profile is not sourced for a non-login shell.

Incorrect. A login bash reads `.profile`, and as it happens, Ubuntu's `.profile` sources `.bashrc`. A non-login, interactive bash reads `.bashrc`. A non-login, **non-interactive** bash invocation does not read `.bashrc` (or `.profile`, for that matter).

When you run `ssh foo command`, the command is run by a non-interactive shell. However, a non-login shell run by SSH is [a special case](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Invoked-by-remote-shell-daemon), and bash reads `.bashrc`. Other shells may or may not read their respective rc files, so it could be the case for some shells that no configuration file is read at all. Bash is not the be-all and end-all of shells.

Non-interactive shells are run for a number of reasons, and usually there's no reason to load the full set of customizations set by a user.

> Why would we want to ignore the profile of user?

See above. Also, SSH has other ways to set environment variables.